# Cordova or Electron for OS X

Tags: angular, macos, cordova, electron

We are developing an application with Angular and Cordova for Android and iOS.
We recently setup Electron to be able to run the app also on desktop.
Both Cordova and Electron supports OS X platform.
The application is using the device file system to store documents and pictures.

Does anyone know which one is the more suitable for OS X?
What are the pros and cons?

Thanks

Comment: We choose to use Electron for Desktop (Windows and OS X) and Cordova for Mobile (iOS and Android).

Comment: Can you please clarify your choice? Why Electron is better than Cordova on  desktop?

Comment: @DmitriyKhudorozhkov It's not a technical choice, just an organizational one. Electron for Desktop, Cordova for mobile (We had to make a choice).